# Текстовое поле для пароля

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Не подскажете как сделать на Win32 API C++ текстовое поле, которое вместо введенных символов отображает специальный (заданный пользователем) символ. Я понял что это делается с помощь CreateWindowEx, но что то у мне не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить к аттрибутам ES_PASSWORD

Например, так

```
CreateWindowEx (WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILDWINDOW|ES_PASSWORD| WS_VISIBLE, 5, 5, 155, 23, h_wnd, .....
```

Comment: Спасибо, лично для меня это - открытие..